# How to convert date time format to another format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date time string like this

`8/14/2015 7:26 AM`, for example, in javascript how can I convert that to this format `March 30, 2015 11:31 AM`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're doing a lot of date logic, it might be worth it to include moment.js in your project. (then you could just do `moment(date).format("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm A")`

Comment: Yep, agreed with @tymeJV -- just use Moment.js. It will solve all your javascript date-time problems instantly. See http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Agree with advice to use moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any reason to use an external library for what is just a few lines of code. Playing around in the console can be good for things like this, since Chrome at least, will show you the available methods that an object has, saving you much time researching MDN/w3schools.

E.g type `var tmp = new Date();` into the console. Now, type `tmp.` and you should see a massive drop-down list of the methods that a Date object has.

Anyway, to solve the problem you present you may use code of the following form. I've not done any error-checking, that's left as an exercise for the reader.

```
function dateTest()
{
    var initialDateStr = "8/14/2015 7:26 AM";
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                  'July', 'August', 'Setember', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    var dateObj = new Date(initialDateStr);

    var outputString = months[ dateObj.getMonth() ] + ' ';
    outputString += dateObj.getDate() + ', ';
    outputString += (dateObj.getYear()+1900) + ' ';

    var hrs12 = dateObj.getHours();
    if (hrs12 > 13)
        outputString += (hrs12-12) + ':';
    else
        outputString += (hrs12) + ':';

    outputString += dateObj.getMinutes() + ' ';

    if (hrs12 > 11)
        outputString += 'PM';
    else
        outputString += 'AM';

    console.log( outputString );
    //August 14, 2015 7:26 AM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an external open-source library for this scenario
[found here](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)